# How to extract a dictionary/list from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

With the following line of code, I can extract a list-like line with beautifulsoup

**Code:**

```
section = soup.find("div", {"class": "listing-col col-sm-16 col-md-12 col-lg-13 col"})

for span in section.select('div.carListing--textCol2'):
    print(span.select_one('shortlist-directive[ng-init]')['ng-init'])
```

Where the output yields a list-esque dictionary-esque line

**Output:**

```
setCurrentListingIdSrp('10856566'); setGAEventDataSrp({"ss_cg_listing_id":10856566,"listingid":10856566,"make":"Audi","model":"A4","transmission":"Manual","body_type":"Wagon","location":"the moon, SolarSystem","Kms":"12,469 km","featured":"No","seller_type":"USED Dealer ad","ss_cg_products":"V"});
```

**Question:**

How can I extract `setGAEventDataSrp` as a Python dictionary?

**What I have tried but didn't work:**

Not the most Pythonic way.

```
for span in section.select('div.carListing--textCol2'):
        data_string = dict(str(span.select_one('shortlist-directive[ng-init]')['ng-init'].split('setGAEventDataSrp(')[-1][:-2]))
```

Comment: what errors did it return, and you are right this is not the most pythonic way of doing things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression.

```
import re
import json
html='''setCurrentListingIdSrp('10856566'); setGAEventDataSrp({"ss_cg_listing_id":10856566,"listingid":10856566,"make":"Audi","model":"A4","transmission":"Manual","body_type":"Wagon","location":"the moon, SolarSystem","Kms":"12,469 km","featured":"No","seller_type":"USED Dealer ad","ss_cg_products":"V"});'''
output=re.findall('\{.*?}',html)[0]
json=json.loads(output)
print(json)
```

Just replace the html to `span.select_one('shortlist-directive[ng-init]')['ng-init']`

Comment: This is definitely more `pro` when compared to my not-so-`pro` approach

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json.loads`

```
>>> import json
>>> type(json.loads('{"a":1, "b":"w"}'))
<class 'dict'>
```

And

```
data_string = json.loads(str(span.select_one('shortlist-directive[ng-init]')['ng-init']).split('setGAEventDataSrp(')[-1][:-2])
```

Comment: This is what I did straight after posted - had a blonde moment... also it should be `json.loads()` not `json_loads()`